# How to turn string into json with php and whitespace and padding

Tags: php, json

I am struggling here. I have looked up many previous answers on this subject and nothing is working.

I have the following string and can't figure out how to get it to a php array. Any ideas?

```
[{  "Account": "XXXXXXXXXXX",  "Transaction ID": 3830251003,  "Timestamp": "05/06/2022 17:21:40",  "Date": 2022-05-06,  "Delta": "50,000.00",  "Amount": "50,000.00",  "Cash Change Type": " Fund Transaction",  "Currency": "USD", },]
```

Comment: This is almost JSON, but has errors if it's intended to be.

Comment: Where did you get that string and what do they say about this format?

Comment: it's coming from a rest api we use and I don't think they are formatting correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get it like a PHP array, store this response in a variable, like $json, and call the function json_decode, like this:

```php
// Do your request...
// I expect your response is stored in a $json variable

$jsonToPhpArray = json_decode($json);

var_dump($jsonToPhpArray);
```

If, of course, your JSON array/object is correctly constructed, it works.
You can try this. In the worst situation you will get a PHP error that can help you, like "Error parsing JSON, malformed JSON"